# How to increase the vm.max_map_count in AWS ECS fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, sonarqube, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to run a sonarqube app on the AWS fargate platform. When I run the raw docker image it works like a charm. But If I pass the JDBC properties to the container as an argument I am facing the following issue. Apparently, the elastic search needs a new config. If it is an ECS cluster I would have ssh into the EC2 instances and update these properties. In the case of fargate, how do I achieve this?

`max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the github issue seems like it not possible as there is no EC2 instance or Host ivolvole in Fargate.

> the workarounds for the `max_map_count` error appear to be setting `max_memory_map` directly on the host (which may result in undesirable side effects, or using the sysctl flag on on the docker run command. **Unfortunately, neither of these options are not supported in Fargate since it involves interacting with the container instance itself.**

But the other way is to increase `file limit` and disable `mmap`  check.

```
I had to properly configure U limits on my ECS task definition, something like:
"ulimits": [
  {
    "name": "nofile",
    "softLimit": 65535,
    "hardLimit": 65535
  }
]
```

> I've disabled mmap in ElasticSearch, which gets rid of the `max_map_count` setting requirement. This can be done by configuring the `sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts SonarQube` setting. I wasn't able to do it with an environment variable since ECS seems to be eating them, but in the end I just passed it as a parameter to the container, which works since the entrypoint is set and consumes arguments properly. In my case:

```
"command": [
  "-Dsonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts=-Dnode.store.allow_mmapfs=false"
]
```

[sonarqube disable nmap](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/issues/282#issuecomment-508507407)

Comment: Thanks for saving my weekend ;-)

Comment: Been banging my head against the keyboard over this, THANK YOU!

Comment: doesn't work for es 5.3, any other workaround?

Comment: To make the multi node Fargate deployment working I had to disable the memory mapping with:
node.store.allow_mmap=false
Still not sure how good that can be and will it reflect the performance but at least the Elasticsearch Cluster is starting now.

Comment: This property has changed to "node.store.allow_mmap". 

`org.sonar.process.MessageException: Property 'node.store.allow_mmapfs' is no longer supported. Use 'node.store.allow_mmap' instead.`

Answer (score 1):

Adding the variable `discovery.type = single-node` under the "Environment Variables" section (edit the es container) in the task definition resolved the issue for me. If you're using the json file, then add the following section

```
"environment": [
        {
          "name": "discovery.type",
          "value": "single-node"
        }
      ],
```

Unfortunately, I don't know why that worked.

Comment: This worked for me too. I did try both approaches for use with ECS using Fargate. I span up a single container today on my machine without the ulimit set, and this was enough to get me across the line.

Comment: When you set `single-mode`, then ELK will ignore `cluster.publish.timeout`.
Maybe it's related with this behavior or some kind of actions when ELK instance search additional nodes.
[Elastic.co > Discovery mode](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-settings.html)