# How to communicate between two services in Fargate using docker compose

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to host Elasticsearch and kibana in AWS ECS (Fargate). I have created a `docker-compose.ym` file

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  es-node:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.0
    deploy:
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 8Gb
    command: > 
        bash -c 
          'bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-smartcn https://github.com/medcl/elasticsearch-analysis-stconvert/releases/download/v7.9.0/elasticsearch-analysis-stconvert-7.9.0.zip;
          /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh'
    container_name: es-$ENV
    environment:
      - node.name=es-$ENV
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.type=single-node
      # - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      # - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=$ES_DB_PASSWORD
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
         awslogs-group: we-two-works-db-ecs-context
         awslogs-region: us-east-1
         awslogs-stream-prefix: es-node
    volumes:
      - elastic_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

  kibana-node:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.9.0
    container_name: kibana-$ENV
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: $ES_DB_URL
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: '["http://es-$ENV:9200"]'
      ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME: elastic
      ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD: $ES_DB_PASSWORD
    networks:
      - elastic
    logging:
      options:
        awslogs-group: we-two-works-db-ecs-context
        awslogs-region: us-east-1
        awslogs-stream-prefix: "kibana-node"

volumes: 
  elastic_data:
    driver_opts:
      performance-mode: maxIO
      throughput-mode: bursting
      uid: 0
      gid: 0

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

and pass in the env variables using `.env.development`file

```
ENV="development"

ES_DB_URL="localhost"
ES_DB_PORT=9200
ES_DB_USER="elastic"
ES_DB_PASSWORD="****"
```

and up the stack in ECS using this command after creating a docker context pointing to ECS `docker compose --env-file ./.env.development up`
However, after creating the stack the kibana node fails to establish communication with the elasticsearch node. Check the logs from kibana node container

```
{
    "type": "log",
    "@timestamp": "2021-12-09T02:07:04Z",
    "tags": [
        "warning",
        "plugins-discovery"
    ],
    "pid": 7,
    "message": "Expect plugin \"id\" in camelCase, but found: beats_management"
}
{
    "type": "log",
    "@timestamp": "2021-12-09T02:07:04Z",
    "tags": [
        "warning",
        "plugins-discovery"
    ],
    "pid": 7,
    "message": "Expect plugin \"id\" in camelCase, but found: triggers_actions_ui"
}
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/plugins/canvas/server/templates/pitch_presentation.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
```

After doing a research I have found that ecs cli does not support `service.networks` docker compose file field and it has given these instructions `Communication between services is implemented by SecurityGroups within the application VPC.`. I am wondering how to set these instructions in the `docker-compose.yml` file because the IP addresses get assigned after stack is being created.

Answer (score 0):

These containers should be able to communicate with each others via their compose service names. So for example the kibana container should be able to reach the ES node using `es-node`. I assume this needs you need to set `ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: '["http://es-node:9200"]'`?

I am also not sure about `ELASTICSEARCH_URL: $ES_DB_URL`. I see you set `ES_DB_URL="localhost"` but that means that the kibana container will be calling `localhost` to try to reach the ES service (this may work on a laptop where all containers run on a flat network but that's not how it will work on ECS - where each compose service is a separate ECS service).

[UPDATE]
I took at stab at the compose file provided. Note that I have simplified it a bit to remove some variables such as the env file, the logging entries (why did you need them? Compose/ECS will create the logging infra for you).

This file works for me (with gotchas - see below):

```
services:
  es-node:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.0
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          memory: 8Gb
    command: > 
        bash -c 
          'bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-smartcn https://github.com/medcl/elasticsearch-analysis-stconvert/releases/download/v7.9.0/elasticsearch-analysis-stconvert-7.9.0.zip;
          /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh'
    container_name: es-node
    environment:
      - node.name=es-node
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=thisisawesome
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
    volumes:
      - elastic_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200

  kibana-node:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.9.0
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          memory: 8Gb
    container_name: kibana-node
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: es-node
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://es-node:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME: elastic
      ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD: thisisawesome

volumes: 
  elastic_data:
    driver_opts:
      performance-mode: maxIO
      throughput-mode: bursting
      uid: 0
      gid: 0
```

There are two major things I had to fix:

1- the kibana task needed more horsepower (the 0.5 vCPU and 512MB of memory - default - was not enough). I set the memory to 8GB (which set the CPU to 1) and the Kibana container came up.

2- I had to increase `ulimits` for the ES container. Some of the error messages in the logs [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62860516/how-to-increase-the-vm-max-map-count-in-aws-ecs-fargate) to max file opened and vm.max_map_count which both pointed to `ulimits` needing being adjusted. For Fargate you need a special section in the task definition. I know there is a way to embed CFN code into the compose file via [overlays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62860516/how-to-increase-the-vm-max-map-count-in-aws-ecs-fargate) but I found easier/quickert to `docker compose convert` the compose into a CFN file and tweak that by adding this section right below the image:

```
        "ulimits": [
          {
            "name": "nofile",
            "softLimit": 65535,
            "hardLimit": 65535
          }
        ]
```

So to recap, you'd need to take my compose above, `convert` it into a CFN file, add the `ulimits` snipped and run it directly in CFN.

You can work backwards from here to re-add your variables etc.

HTH

Comment: I ran it after changing `ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: '["http://es-node:9200"]` and set the `ELASTICSEARCH_URL:<service>.<compose_project_name>.local` as suggested in here - [link](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/#service-discovery) under service discovery section. but still the issue seems to be persist.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but are you using actually `<service>.<compose_project_name>.local` or are you replacing `<service>` and `<compose_project_name>` with the actual names? (the service in your case should be `es-node` and the  `<compose_project_name>` by default is the folder you are launching the compose up command from.

Comment: Given they are in the same compose I think you can omit `<compose_project_name>.local` as it's assumed. Can you try with `ELASTICSEARCH_URL: 'es-node'` ?

Comment: No worries, I have replaced them with the actual values. I will try this `ELASTICSEARCH_URL: 'es-node'` and see how it goes. Thank you

Comment: Edited my answer with a "work around"